# Is there any way to create a column of GUID type in pyspark/sql databricks?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, uuid, guid

I want to create a delta table with a column of GUID type. Column should not have autogenerated values I will populate the column explicitly. It should just have a GUID type. How can I do this?

Comment: `df.withColumn(guidCol, lit("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))`  Guids are nothing but string datatype.